# How can I push consecutive same elements into subarrays?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-1.8.7

For example,

input = `['a','b','b','b','a','a','b','c','c']`

output = `['a',['b','b','b'],['a','a'],'b',['c','c']]`

Here, if there are more than one same elements then those are put into sub-array.

Can you please help me out?

Comment: Ruby 1.8.7 is *ancient*. And it is no longer supported. You tagged your question with [tag:ruby-on-rails] and [tag:ruby-1.8.7], which makes me very nervous. Are you *really* running a website off a version of Ruby that has been unsupported for almost a year, and does not receive any security fixes? Note that after support for Ruby 1.8.7 ended, at least one serious vulnerability has been found: [CVE-2013-4164: *Heap-based buffer overflow in Ruby 1.8 […] allows context-dependent attackers to […] possibly execute arbitrary code […]*](http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2013-4164)

Comment: Homework question? What have you tried? What was the result?

Comment: @Pavling Humm. Now-a-days we provide answers to homework questions also in SO. No problem here... :-)

Comment: @JörgWMittag: although I understand your anger (in the company where I am the CTO I upgrade Ruby as soon as possible), there are some contexts where Ruby 1.8.7 is acceptable; for example on a Debian server, which provides a fully patched version of Ruby 1.8.7

Comment: @ArupRakshit you might, but I won't (seeing as I set questions as homework... it would be a bit pointless to answer them too) - and since it's a community, we're both free to follow our own preferences. There are discussions about this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @Pavling What you are saying true.. I meant to say, we are not following, but we should.. I am with you.. :-)

Answer (score 4):

This solution uses a sneaky trick to prevent having to check if a list element is either a single element or an Array already. By doing `[*list[-1]]` we make sure to always end up with an Array, regardless of whether the last element in the `list` we are building was a single element (e.g., `'a'`) or an Array already (e.g., `['b','b']`). Then, we check if the first element of that Array (could be any element, they are all the same) is equal to the element of `input` we are currently processing. If so, we append it to the created Array. Otherwise, we just append it to `list` since it is different from the previous element.

```
input = ['a','b','b','b','a','a','b','c','c']

output = input.reduce([]) do |list, e|
  last = [*list[-1]]
  if last[0] == e
    list[-1] = last << e
  else
    list << e
  end
  list
end

p output
# ["a", ["b", "b", "b"], ["a", "a"], "b", ["c", "c"]]
```

Alternatively, with checking specifically for the type of the element it would be something like this:

```
output = input.reduce([]) do |list, e|
  last = list.last
  if last.is_a? Array and last.include? e
    last << e
  elsif last == e
    list[-1] = [last, e]
  else
    list << e
  end
  list
end
```

This was tested on Ruby 2.0, but it should run fine on 1.8.7 as well.

Comment: I like [*my_arr[i]].  It is sadly not obvious to engineers disinterested in style-isms

Comment: @NewAlexandria Fair point, although they can just use the alternative implementation where it's very obvious what's going on :) I will change that one slightly to improve readability a bit more.

Comment: oh, no!, I like the concise form.  I just wanted to draw attention to the care needed when implementing it

Answer (score 4):

Ruby 1.9+ has [`Enumerable#chunk`](http://Ruby-Doc.Org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk), which will almost do what you want:

```
input.
  chunk {|e| e }.
  map(&:last).
  map {|e| if e.size == 1 then e.first else e end }
```

For older versions of Ruby, `Enumerable#chunk` is available in Marc-André Lafortunes [`backports`](https://RubyGems.Org/gems/backports/) gem. Just add

```
require 'backports/1.9.2/enumerable/chunk'
```

on top.

Comment: Gotta love Ruby for all sorts of built-ins. Although this solution has to iterate the whole input 3 times as opposed to once (with `chunk`, `map`, `map`). Then again, scalability is not really a concern here :)

Comment: I would implement this style more, for readability.  I have seen otherwise-smart engineers at big firms cry when having to look at things that are spelled-out any less than this.  Pity, but the cultural norm of the trade

Answer (score 0):

I was under the impression that, this problem can be solved using [`slice_before`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before). But couldn't figured out. Finally  [Robert Klemme](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4663373#1145571) has guided me in the proper direction. Hope you guys would also like it.

```
input = ['a','b','b','b','a','a','b','c','c']
prev = nil
input.slice_before { |e| (e != prev).tap { prev = e } }.
      map { |elem| elem.size == 1 ? elem.first : elem }
# => ["a", ["b", "b", "b"], ["a", "a"], "b", ["c", "c"]]
```